# Subscribing to a public Google calendar with Python

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I have a public calendar and I want users to be able to subscribe to that calendar. Any idea how to subscribe or insert an existing calendar into a users google calendar list?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CalendarList: insert method to do this:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert

```
my_calendar_id = 'some calendar id'
calendar_list_entry = {
    'id': my_calendar_id
}

created_calendar_list_entry = service.calendarList().insert(body=calendar_list_entry).execute()
```